# How to use QueryPerformanceCounter to test performance of existing code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, counter, query-performance

I have an existing project in Visual Studio, with a main file that calls a function file. I also created a CodeTimer.cpp following the steps from the Microsoft guide, and I placed it along with the necessary headers in the same directory as my code and function.

The issue is, I don't know how to *link* them. The solution builds fine, all three files combine with no errors. But when I CTRL-F5 it, I just see the output of my main, for obvious reasons (I didn't link the CodeTimer to the main).

This is my CodeTimer:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace System;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __int64 ctr1 = 0, ctr2 = 0, freq = 0;
    int acc = 0, i = 0;

    // Start timing the code.
    if (QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ctr1) != 0)
    {
        // Code segment is being timed.
        for (i = 0; i<100; i++) acc++;

        // Finish timing the code.
        QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ctr2);

        Console::WriteLine("Start Value: {0}", ctr1.ToString());
        Console::WriteLine("End Value: {0}", ctr2.ToString());

        QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *)&freq);

        Console::WriteLine("QueryPerformanceFrequency : {0} per Seconds.", freq.ToString());
        Console::WriteLine("QueryPerformanceCounter minimum resolution: 1/{0} Seconds.", freq.ToString());
        Console::WriteLine("ctr2 - ctr1: {0} counts.", ((ctr2 - ctr1) * 1.0 / 1.0).ToString());
        Console::WriteLine("65536 Increments by 1 computation time: {0} seconds.", ((ctr2 - ctr1) * 1.0 / freq).ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        Console::WriteLine("Error value = {0}", dwError.ToString());
    }

    // Make the console window wait.
    Console::WriteLine();
    Console::Write("Press ENTER to finish.");
    Console::Read();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NVM fixed it. Just had to add the body of _tmain() in main() function under my code, and get ride of the CodeTimer.cpp file completely. It was a conflict of mains (multiple mains in one project, the compiler automatically outputted the one with the highest priority in the project).